# alter precision of column of a view that is the result of a coalesce

Tags: sql-server, ssms, alter, sql-view

I have found several posts online about altering columns of stored procedures and several about altering views - a couple of them being: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/modify-columns-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017. What has prompted this whole query is the fact that our version control software flagged a change in the field characteristics. It used to be (30,15) but now it is (28,13)
Original:

```
''' Mapped on view Field: ViewName.Function<br/>
''' View field characteristics (type, precision, scale, length): Decimal, 30, 15, 0</remarks>
```

is now:

```
''' View field characteristics (type, precision, scale, length): Decimal, 28, 13, 0</remarks>
```

Something tells me that the underlying view / function has to be changed to output the (30,15), though as far as I can tell, nothing has been changed in this view for years. Currently give ViewName.Function evaluates to DECIMAL(12,2). As a side note, I'm having a bit of a challenge understanding how DECIMAL(12,2) is being treated as (28,13) by SSMS. Currently when I go to SSMS > DatabaseName > Views > dbo.ViewName > Columns > AliasName > right click > Properties > Numeric Precision: 28, Numeric Scale: 13. Also, when I right click on the dbo.ViewName > Design, the column contains the coalesce function that has the (28,13) precision. When I right click on that coalesce function and go to properties it just shows the generic properties for the View.
Anyroad, I need to find a way to get it back to the  original characteristics. Hopefully my query makes sense. Please let me know if I need to share any additional information.

Comment: Why doesn't your view just apply the conversion you want? `SELECT col = CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,15), <expression>), ...`

Comment: @AaronBertrand Aaron thank you for your suggestion. So my syntax would be something like SELECT AliasName CONVERT(DECIMAL(30, 15), DECIMAL(12,2))? I'm not sure what Expression should be even after looking at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 Alright, hang on, I think I might have it.

Answer (score 0):

@AaronBertrand provided the answer. My final code was something like this:

```
SELECT AliasName = CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,15), [the COALESCE function, etc.]).
```

Thank you sir!!